# Python regex to match API paths

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need a regex that matches api path with the below rules

1. path begins with '/' but can have more than one '/'
2. '/' must be followed by a word begining with lower case, but can have upper case later on

   ```
   x = ["/word/worD/sdfsfsd","/fsdfsdf","/","/{sfsdf",'/','/_','/{','/{"type":"tnt"}',"/allGear{Exe","/Grear"]

   import re

   pattern = re.compile("(/[a-z][a-zA-Z]+)+")

   for y in x:
        print (pattern.match(y))
   ```

So in this example only the 1st two elements must generate a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the job for you. But, again as said in a comment, I think given your description `/allGear{Exe` should also be included. The code I have given returns this also

```
 x = ["/word/worD/sdfsfsd","/fsdfsdf","/","/{sfsdf",'/','/_','/{','/{"type":"tnt"}',"/allGear{Exe","/Grear"]


import re

for i in x:
    pattern = re.search("""\/[a-z][a-zA-Z]+""", i, re.S)
#If you don't want the /allGear, change the regex to """\/[a-z][a-zA-Z]+$""";
    if(pattern is not None):
        print i
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following approach:

```
import re
x = ["/word/worD/sdfsfsd","/fsdfsdf","/","/{sfsdf",'/','/_','/{','/{"type":"tnt"}',"/allGear{Exe","/Grear"]
result = [p for p in x if re.match(r'^(\/[a-z][a-zA-z]+)+$', p)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['/word/worD/sdfsfsd', '/fsdfsdf']
```